# Datanodes are active but I'm not able to copy files to HDFS [Hadoop 2.6.0 - Raspberry Pi Cluster]

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, raspberry-pi2

I have been working on **Hadoop Cluster using Raspberry Pis**, just for learning purposes. I have configured all the Slaves and a Master successfully (As far as i think).

**Problem:** HDFS is not able to copy local files. And According to *http://Master:8088* i have 3 active nodes. (I attached a screenshot at end)

But when i try to copy a Local file to HDFS, i get below exception:

```
16/01/12 06:20:43 WARN hdfs.DFSClient: DataStreamer Exception
org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(java.io.IOException): File /LICENCE.txt._COPYING_ could only be replicated to 0 nodes instead of minReplication (=1).  There are 0 datanode(s) running and no node(s) are excluded in this operation.
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.blockmanagement.BlockManager.chooseTarget4NewBlock(BlockManager.java:1549)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getAdditionalBlock(FSNamesystem.java:3200)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeRpcServer.addBlock(NameNodeRpcServer.java:641)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.addBlock(ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.java:482)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.proto.ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos$ClientNamenodeProtocol$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos.java)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:619)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:962)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2039)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2035)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1628)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:2033)

        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1468)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1399)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:232)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy9.addBlock(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.addBlock(ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.java:399)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:187)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:102)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy10.addBlock(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.locateFollowingBlock(DFSOutputStream.java:1532)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.nextBlockOutputStream(DFSOutputStream.java:1349)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.run(DFSOutputStream.java:588)
put: File /LICENCE.txt._COPYING_ could only be replicated to 0 nodes instead of minReplication (=1).  There are 0 datanode(s) running and no node(s) are excluded in this operation.
```

Below are my **configurations on Slaves and Master**:

**core-site.xml:**

```
<configuration>
<property>
<name>fs.default.name</name>
<value>hdfs://Master:9000</value>
</property>
</configuration>
```

**mapred-site.xml**

```
<configuration>
<property>
      <name>mapreduce.framework.name</name>
      <value>yarn</value>
</property>
<property>
        <name>mapreduce.job.tracker</name>
        <value>Master:5431</value>
</property>>
</configuration>
```

**hdfs-site.xml**

```
<configuration>
 <property>
      <name>dfs.namenode.name.dir</name>
      <value>file:/usr/local/hadoop_tmp/hdfs/namenode</value>
 </property>
 <property>
      <name>dfs.datanode.data.dir</name>
      <value>file:/usr/local/hadoop_tmp/hdfs/datanode</value>
 </property>
 <property>
  <name>dfs.replication</name>
  <value>4</value>
 </property>
</configuration>
```

**yarn-site.xml**

```
<configuration>
<property>
      <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services</name>
      <value>mapreduce_shuffle</value>
</property>
<property>
      <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services.mapreduce.shuffle.class</name>
      <value>org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ShuffleHandler</value>
</property>
<property>
        <name>yarn.resourcemanager.resource-tracker.address</name>
        <value>Master:8025</value>
</property>
<property>
        <name>yarn.resourcemanager.scheduler.address</name>
        <value>Master:8035</value>
</property>
<property>
        <name>yarn.resourcemanager.address</name>
        <value>Master:8050</value>
</property>
</configuration>
```

When i run **JPS** on Master:

```
1218 ResourceManager
2147 Jps
1034 SecondaryNameNode
879 NameNode
```

When i run **JPS** on Slaves:

```
1270 Jps
1118 NodeManager
```

[image: Active Node Screenshot]
I would really be thankful to you all, Please help me through it. I searched on StackoverFlow tried many things but couldn't fix it. Deleted temporary directories, formatted namenode and datanode already.

IF you require anything else for debugging purposes, I'll be right here.

Thanks a lot!

Regards,
Maher Shahmeer

Comment: I updated my answer. Please check http://stackoverflow.com/a/34740564/5678086

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `hdfs-site.xml` should be different for slaves and master.

1. Name node setting has to be

   ```
   <configuration>
    <property>
     <name>dfs.namenode.name.dir</name>
     <value>file:/usr/local/hadoop_tmp/hdfs/namenode</value>
    </property>
   <property>
     <name>dfs.replication</name>
     <value>4</value>
    </property>
   </configuration>
   ```
2. And All the slave nodes should have the below setting

   ```
   <configuration>
    <property>
     <name>dfs.datanode.data.dir</name>
     <value>file:/usr/local/hadoop_tmp/hdfs/datanode</value>
    </property>
    <property>
     <name>dfs.replication</name>
     <value>4</value>
    </property>
   </configuration>
   ```
3. And your `slaves` configuration file should include all IPs of your data nodes.

Finally stop and restart your hadoop cluster. The issue will be fixed. Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

I cant seem to find datanode process running on your slave/master

Comment: Can you please guide me a little ? So i can know what to debug ?